# Parsing FORM-ENCODED parameters with GRAILS (chargify webhooks)

Tags: java, grails, chargify

I have a GRAILS 3 controller that receive an HTTP post from a webservice (`Chargify`) with this format (the payload section has about 100 entries with a lot of sub-fields):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*; q=0.5, application/xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Chargify-Webhook-Id: 81309408
X-Chargify-Webhook-Signature: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Chargify-Webhook-Signature-Hmac-Sha-256: yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
Content-Length: 48
User-Agent: Ruby
X-Newrelic-Id: xxxxxx
X-Newrelic-Transaction: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa=
Host: myhost.test.it

id=81197881&event=statement_settled&payload[site][id]=12345&payload[site][subdomain]=test-sandbox
```

Is there any way with **GRAILS to parse the "payload" part and convert it dynamically to a POJO (or also a simple hashmap)**?. `Chargify` use this strange format not recognized by `GRAILS framework` and I'm unable to parse it automatically.

Is there anyone to help me for parsing? Advance thanks for helping.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly.. the part at the end of your example starting with ID is the body of the Post request, or is it part of the URL?

Comment: Is the body of the request

Comment: I don't see any built in way to automatically parse the request body into a pogo. Are you open to other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
def readChargify() {
    String requestData = request.reader.text
    def reqMap = org.grails.web.util.WebUtils.fromQueryString(requestData)
}
```

Comment: It does not work, for example from the request body 
`id=81197881&event=statement_settled&payload[site][id]=12345&payload[site][subdomain]=test-sandbox`
it will create a request map like:
`[id:81197881, event:statement_settled, payload[site][id] : 12345, payload[site][subdomain] : test-sandbox]`

and not a nested map like
`{id='81197881', event='statement_settled', site=Site{subdomain='test-sandbox', id='12345'}}`

Answer (score 0):

This Java library to parse the body of webhooks was contributed by another Chargify customer and may be helpful:

https://github.com/prowave/chargify-webhook-java